# React Router v4 renders multiple routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm creating an SPA and I'm trying to setup Routing in the application using the `react-router-dom` package version `4.1.1`.

My Route Definition is below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="404" component={NotFound} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Basically, I want to setup routing so that any request to a page for which no route is defined goes to the `{NotFound}` component.

How can this be achieved?
The solution above renders both the `Login` and the `NotFound` component when requesting the `/login` page.

Kind regards

Answer (score 31, accepted):

here's an example from [official tutorial](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch), how to avoid rendering multiple routes

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  <Route path="/:user" component={User}/>
  <Route component={NoMatch}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: `<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
     <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/child" component={Child} />
      </Switch>
       // Default Route - FAILS
       <Route path="*" Component={NotFound404} />
</Switch>
`

Switch inside Switch is failing to load the Default Route..

Any idea on how to achieve the default Route when using switch inside switch?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. I am unable to beautify it in comments

Comment: @NitinKumar ```All children of a <Switch> should be <Route> or <Redirect> elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.``` according to [official docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md), so avoid using nested switches

Answer (score 14):

Make use of `Switch` to render the first match of the route, You need to import `Switch` before using

```
import {Switch} from 'react-router';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="404" component={NotFound} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

According to the **[docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch)**

> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In
>   contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders
>   inclusively.
>
> Now, if we’re at `/login`, `<Switch>` will start looking for a
>   matching `<Route>`. `<Route path="/login"/>` will match and `<Switch>`
>   will stop looking for matches and render `<Login>`. otherwise route
>   matches `/login` with `/login` and `*` and renders both the routes

However, when using Switch the order of Routes matter, make sure that you are adding the prefix Routes after the other Routes. For e.g. '/home' must be after '/' in the Route order or else, you could make use of the `exact` prop

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
```

Comment: is not good solution. when go to /login from / then Login component Unmount and mount and is not good for performence

Answer (score 0):

I think NotFound page is rendered because of `<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />` rule. Path property of the Router accepts **Any valid URL path that path-to-regexp understands.** So '*' means zero or more parameter matches