# how to set multiple routes in Hashrouter in reactjs that every page open in new page not append

Tags: php, reactjs

> so '/' is for home page and '/about' for about us page but when i am 
>           going to home to about my about us page content is append at the end of 
>           the home page please help me thank you

---

```js
import {HashRouter, Route,Router,browserHistory,Link,Switch}         from 'react-
        router-dom';
        
       <HashRouter handler={App}>
        <span>
        <Route path={'/'} component={TodoComponent}></Route>
        <Route path={'/about'} component={About}></Route>
        </span>
        </HashRouter>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try adding `exact` to `Route` `/` like <Route exact path={'/'} component={TodoComponent}></Route>

Comment: This question is a more appropriate duplicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994510/react-router-v4-renders-multiple-routes/43994605#43994605

Comment: thanx i found the correct way i just put "exact" in the '/'  route

Answer (score 0):

i use this code in my router

```js
<Route exact path={'/'} component={TodoComponent}></Route>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

insted of

```js
<Route path={'/'} component={TodoComponent}></Route>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```