# react router component props doesn't accept <Link /> component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

What's wrong with this?

```
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
<Route path='/' component={() => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
        <Link to='/users'>Users</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }}
/>
```

I got error of

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

but if I just do this it's fine

```
<Route path='/' component={() => {
    return (
      <div>
        Home
      </div>
    )
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Link` component is not an export in `react-router` package but `react-router-dom`

You need to install it using

```
npm install -S react-router-dom
```

and then use it like

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Route path='/' render={(props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
        <Link to='/users'>Users</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }}
/>
```

Also when using a functional component inline in `Route` make use of `render` and not `component` prop with the functional argument as props

Comment: ah no wonder, but any clue why the <Link /> is not clickable here? https://codesandbox.io/s/jz245lr48v

Comment: and to save npm package you just need `npm i` right?

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994510/react-router-v4-renders-multiple-routes/43994605#43994605

you need to write `<Switch>
    <Route path='/users' component={UsersContainer} />
    <Route path='/' render={(props) => <div>Content for Home</div>} />
   </Switch>`