# React router: route renders two components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following routes in my react app:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
<Route exact path="/:category" component={HomeScreen} />
<Route exact path="/:category/:id" component={PostDetailScreen} />
<Route exact path="/posts/new" component={CreatePostScreen} />
```

When I go to /posts/new my app not only renders CreatePostScreen but also PostDetailScreen. I think it interprets :category = posts and :id = new.

However, I am stuck. What am I doing wrong? I just want to have the /posts/new route rendering CreatePostScreen.

Comment: If you use exact, it shouldn't render both the components, Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994510/react-router-v4-renders-multiple-routes/43994605#43994605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Route exact path="/posts/new" component={CreatePostScreen} />
  <Route exact path="/:category" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Route exact path="/:category/:id" component={PostDetailScreen} />
</Switch>
```

`/posts/new` is a valid path that satisfies `/:category/:id` i.e. your category is `posts` id is `new`

Placing routes in `<Switch>` renders first one that matches, more info here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Answer (score 1):

React router interprets “posts” as a category and “new“ as ID.

Change the order of the *Route* components, and use a [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md) component, like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Route exact path="/posts/new" component={CreatePostScreen} />
    <Route exact path="/:category" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Route exact path="/:category/:id" component={PostDetailScreen} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Awesome! Does it! Thanks!