# Routes not rendering with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

My site's entering scenario is

```
/ -> /home
     -> /about
     -> /project
```

When connect to `site.com/`, there is welcome message and enter button.

After click the 'enter' button, `/home` will be show.

And `/home` has Navbar that has two components `/about` and `/project`

So, user can click the navbar menu to navigate another page.

/about is works properly, but /project doesn't work. It displayed blank page.

[App.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Project from './components/Project';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Home.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import Project from '../Project';
import About from '../About';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import {
    Navbar,
    NavbarBrand,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

class index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="home">
                    <Header />
                    <Route path="/home" component={About}/>
                    <Route path="/project" component={Project}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default index;
```

[Header.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

class index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar_fixed">
            <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
              <NavbarBrand href="/">Hide</NavbarBrand>
                <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink href="/home">About</NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink href="/project">Project</NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default index;
```

[About.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';

export default class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         Some codes for About.js
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Project.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';

export default class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       Some codes for Project.js
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I entered to `/home`, It shows About.js component with navbar.

[image]

But entered to `/project`, It show nothing.

[image]

I can't find where is the error.

How can I fixed it?

Thanks.

---

[SOLVED]

Change the code to Shubham Khatri's code and add exact to `<Route exact path="/home" component={About}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Header component isn't receiving the react-router props and hence its navigation doesn't work properly, You could write Header as a default Route. Also you need to use BrowserRouter only once at the top of your App

Also with nested Route, you need to specify the relative routes

```
class index extends Component {
    render() {
        const { match } = this.props;
        return (
                <div className="home">
                    <Route component={Header} />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path={`${match.path}/project`} component={Project}/>
                        <Route path="/home" component={About}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and your Header.js will be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

class index extends Component {
    render() {
        const { match } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="navbar_fixed">
            <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
              <NavbarBrand href="/">Hide</NavbarBrand>
                <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink href="/home">About</NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink href={`${match.url}/project`}>Project</NavLink>
                  </NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default index;
```

Comment: I fixed Home.js code to your code. But /project still shows nothing.

Comment: You mean delete the <BrowserRouter>? After delete it, still show nothing.

Comment: Updated the answer again, you need to specify relative routes while navigating since,Home contains `/project` and Home is defined at `/home` and hence /project must be `/home/project`

Comment: Thanks. But after modifed code, another errors has occured. When I entered to /home/project, Abous.js and Project.js shows together at one page. (/home is works perfectly)

Comment: I added `exact` to path, then it works. Thanks for comment!

Comment: Updated the answer for that too. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994510/react-router-v4-renders-multiple-routes/43994605#43994605