# react-router-dom not rendering components on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

If I click on a navigation link, I can see that the slug has changed but the component is not rendering. I have to manually refresh the page in order to see the component, while the page should re-render by itself on route/slug change.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Me from './components/me';
import Contrib from './components/contrib';
import Projects from './components/projects';
import Contact from './components/contact';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Me} />
            <Route path="/contrib" component={Contrib} />
            <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

header.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src={Earth} alt="placeholdit" className="rounded" />
            </div>
            <nav>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <ul>
                        <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/contrib">Contributions</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/projects">Projects</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If I remove the `<BrowserRouter>` from `header.jsx` I get an error telling me that: **"You should not use `<Route>` or `withRouter()` outside a `<Router>`"**.

If add the `<BrowserRouter>` inside of `header.jsx` the error is gone, but the components are not rendering on route/slug change.

Comment: How is you topmost component structured? Where are you using `Header` and `App`?

Comment: I tried to create the app using `create-react-app` and added `Header` in `src/index.js` -> `ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('header'));` . The reason I did this, is because I don't want my whole site to be in `<div id="root"></div>` but rather to have `<header>, <main> and <footer>`. The `App` is also in `src/index.js` that CLI generates.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you not render your topmost component in e.g. `document.body` and have the topmost component be e.g. `<BrowserRouter><Header /><Main /><Footer /></BrowserRouter>` instead? The reason why your URL is updating but your components aren't is because you use multiple `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: I suspected that the reason is `BrowserRouter` but I wasn't sure. I'll try it, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yup, it works now. Thank you. I had to wrap it in a `<div>` since it complains that `A <Router> may have only one child element`. So here's the code that works in `App.js` -> `<BrowserRouter>
          <div>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Me} />
            <Route path="/contrib" component={Contrib} />
            <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>`

Comment: Oh and one more reason I was avoiding putting everything in `<div id="root"></div>` is because Audit tool from [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) is complaining about missing `<header>, <main>` and `<footer>` tags in HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-router-dom doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325836/react-router-dom-doesnt-work-properly/50325965#50325965)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap  around the highest order component for it to work as expected. If your app is simple, wrap it within ReactDOM.render method. Like so

```
ReactDOM.render((
<BrowserRouter>
  <App/>
</BrowserRouter>),
document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Delete the  from header.jsx and put it in your index.js like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Be careful with the order** of *Route*, *Switch* and *Router*. I follow this order and it works for me.
**Note:** Try to use the Arrow function

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
// Containers
import { Dashboard, CardPayment } from "../Containers";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const ReactRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/card-payment" component={CardPayment} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact={true} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default ReactRouter;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a Router  was used, and downgrading the "history" library fixed the problem.

app.tsx

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${AppRoute.ALBUMS}/:author/:album`} component={PhotosPage}/>
    <Route exact path={`${AppRoute.ALBUMS}/:id`} component={AlbumsPage}/>
    <Route path={AppRoute.ERROR} component={ErrorPage}/>
    <Route path={AppRoute.ROOT} component={AuthorsPage}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Versions in my project:

package.json:

```
...
"history": "4.10.1",
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
...
```

The "history" library was originally version "5.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

Check the Index.js , Remove the Strict Mode and the render.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
//Remove these 
  // <React.StrictMode>
  //   <App />
  // </React.StrictMode>
// Add these
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who couldn't fix this error

Step 1: Make sure the higher order component wrapped with Router. In the above question it's already done.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Me} />
            <Route path="/contrib" component={Contrib} />
            <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Let's consider `<Header/>` sits inside the any of the components in the `<Route/>`

Step 2: If higher order component already wrapped with `Router`, don't wrap the `<Header/>` also, if you don't want separate routing inside the `<Header/>`.

```
import { NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src={Earth} alt="placeholdit" className="rounded" />
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                        <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/contrib">Contributions</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/projects">Projects</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<Link to ={"/home"}>Home</Link>
```

In my case
I forgot to add brackets to "to" parameter then it is rendering components

Comment: it will work in both ways `to="/home" or t0={"/home"}`