# react router one path point on two component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In `ReactJS` , I have this routes:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/:id" component={Profile}/>
<Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
```

when I request

> www.example.com/username

I get the `Profile` component as expected, but the problem is 
when I request

> www.example.com/settings

the page render two components at the same time
first I get the `Profile` component and below it, I get `Settings` component

how can I handle this case in React JS?

Comment: Change the order of`<Route path="/:id" component={Profile}/>
<Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>`  to `<Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/> <Route path="/:id" component={Profile}/>
`

Comment: @HardikModha the same thing, if I changed the order then the order of the components in the same page will be changed, I mean now I get Settings component at first then Profile component

Comment: use exact={true} prop in settings route. <Route path=''settings" exact={true} component={Settings} />

Comment: the correct answer is here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994560/2609219) 
I need to add `<Switch>`  tag to avoid rendering multiple routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `<Switch>` tag to avoid rendering multiple routes

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
<BrowserRouter>
       <div className="sans-serif">
          <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
             <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
             <Route path="/:id" component={Profile}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both location path are same, you need to use `exact`, so you may use like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
<Route path="/:id" component={Profile}/>
```

But why not use profile path like this?

```
<Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile}/>
```

A much better experience.

Comment: this doesn't work with me, I wrote the answer in the post