# Mutliple components rendered in React JS using Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

I have tried using `<Switch>` and `exact` after viewing this post: [React Router v4 renders multiple routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994510/react-router-v4-renders-multiple-routes) but it hasn't resolved my problem, which is that 2 of my components are rendered at the same time when the `<Link>` function operates.

**The code:**

```
import React from "react";
import '../styles/Onboarding.css';
import {Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function ComponentA() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="parent">
        <h1 className="title">title</h1>
        <p className="description">description</p>
        <Link exact to="/componentB"><button className="button">enter</button></Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/componentB" component={ComponentB} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}


function ComponentB() {
  return (
    <div>
      Welcome to ComponentB
    </div>
  )
}

export default ComponentA;
```

The result is the html of Component A showing up and "Welcome to ComponentB" underneath them. Please help me out with this `reaact-router` issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of `ComponentA` shows up because `ComponentB` is now a child route of `ComponentA`. To render them separately, need a parent component like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/componentA" component={ComponentA} />
          <Route exact path="/componentB" component={ComponentB} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit focused-neumann-mm8qb]